# How do I specify path to dll in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, header-files, msys2

I have installed library [arb](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb), [flint](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/flint2), [GMP](https://github.com/alisw/GMP). [MPFR](https://github.com/aixoss/mpfr)
all in dynamic mode (ie with `--disable-static` option)

When I run

`g++ test_arb.cpp`

it is able to locate the path of the headers properly from `/mingw64/include` and therefore the function defined within it are working fine.
But not the functions which are in dll files which got installed at `/mingw64/lib/*.dll`

`.h`files got installed in `/mingw64/include`
`.dll` files got installed in `/mingw64/lib`

for example `arb_fprintd` is declared in `/mingw64/include/arb.h` but defined in `/mingw64/lib/libarb2.dll` is not being detected.

> /mingw64/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw64/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-mingw64/bin/ld:
> /tmp/ccCn19iJ.o:test_arb.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to
> `arb_fprintd'

[The files in `/mingw64/lib` and `/mingw64/include`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgTF.png)

PS:I am on windows 10. I am using gcc via msys2 platform installed via packman ;

```
pacman -S base-devel gcc vim cmake
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

The path to the default gcc is `/mingw64/bin/`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245533/discussion-on-question-by-masruka-jannat-how-do-i-specify-path-to-dll-in-gcc).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to link against /mingw64/lib/libarb2.dll.a, which should be an import library for libarb2.dll?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question above? If yes then write a more affirmativa text like _You should link against...._ If instead this is a request for a clarification then post this as a comment.